# HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden asp.net 4 & MVC 5 iis10 windows server 2022 target framework 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I have windows server 2022 and i did all configuration as well as deployed my asp.net 4 with MVC 5 with target framework 4.6.1 application login page are shown but after login it say 403 forbidden please see the screen shots below:

I google from last 2 days and apply several things but no luck see my webconfig below as well after i apply my searches result but still not got any successs:

```
<appSettings> 
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

[see screen shot:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HS0N.png)
[see screen shot:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7AcZ.png)

On server I install required things for that also for adding server roles and features as well:

On IIS side i do all things as well see below:

Please advise.

[Network tell of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7AcZ.png)

[see screen shot iis configuration done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HS0N.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Check what FRT says.

Comment: Could you provide sub-status code and detailed error information about 403?

Comment: session is not maintain on server even I do the configuration: see :<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"><remove name="FormsAuthentication" /> <remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
  </modules>                       
we got null on OnActionExecuting method: if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session == null || System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["EflowSession"] == null)

Comment: 403 means you don't have permission to access the folder, this is a security issue, try enabling anonymous authentication in your IIS application.